# Get all elements in array besides the first one.. ? (php)

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style

Is there a way to specify getting all but the first element in an array?  I generally use foreach() to loop through my arrays.

say array(1,2,3,4,5), i would only want 2, 3, 4 ,5 to show and for it to skip 1.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are multiple ways of approaching this problem.

The first solution is to use a flag boolean to indicate the first element and proceed in your [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)

```
$firstElement = true;

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  if($firstElement) {
    $firstElement = false;
  } else {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
  }
}
```

If your elements are naturally numerically indexed, you do not need the boolean flag, you can simply check if the key is 0.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  if($key === 0) continue;      

  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

---

The second way is to cheat your way into a naturally numerically indexed array if it isn't already. I will use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) to get a naturally numerically indexed array of keys and loop it.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

foreach($keys as $index => $key) {
  if($index === 0) continue;   

  $val = $array[$key];
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

---

The third way is to use the array internal pointer to skip the first element and then continue in a loop by using [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset), [`next()`](http://php.net/next), [`list()`](http://php.net/list), and [`each()`](http://php.net/each). **Performance and resource-wise, this is the best option. Maintainability suffers greatly though.**

```
reset($array); // Reset pointer to 0
next($array);  // Advance pointer to 1

while (list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

---

If you don't mind losing the first element of the array, you can [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) it.

```
array_shift($array);

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

---

You can also [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) the array. I'm also using [`count()`](http://php.net/count) in order to be able to set the [`preserve_keys`](http://php.net/array_slice) parameter to `true`.

```
$sliced = array_slice($array, 1, count($array)-1, true);

foreach($sliced as $key => $val) {
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't have thought of reset/next. Nice.

Comment: Well, i happen to have falen in love with Javascript's Underscore.js and im glad they have a PHP version called Underscore.php. It has nice functions of interacting with collections (arrays, objects etc). For example to do the above you just do `__::rest(array(1,2,3,4,5))` and it gives you `array(2,3,4,5)`. Its so simple to use.

Comment: Note you can supply `null` as the third argument to `array_slice()` in order to use `preserve_keys` but not have to calculate the length required.

Comment: array_slice is a MUCH better solution

Answer (score 59):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$all_but_the_first_element_array = array_slice($arr, 1);
```

Comment: YAY! An immutable version of array_shift()!

Answer (score 10):

array_shift()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

example used in the site:

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_shift($stack);
print_r($stack);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
)
```

**remember that the pointer to the array is reset (new value) after the shift

Comment: mutates the original array, ugly :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, there can be many ways for that as we have great deal of array-manipulation functions available. However i use the following method for that:

```
$orig_array = array(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5);
array_shift($orig_array);
print_r($orig_array);
```