# PHP how to skip first element in while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, time, while-loop

i have function to get time between two time, i want this code print like this

> Array ( [0] => 07:00:00 [1] => 08:00:00 [2] => 09:00:00 [3] =>
>   10:00:00 [4] => 11:00:00 )

(first element not printed/added)

this below code print like this.

> Array ( [0] => 06:00:00 [1] => 07:00:00 [2] => 08:00:00 [3] =>
>   09:00:00 [4] => 10:00:00 [5] => 11:00:00 )

the code

```
$si="06:00 AM";
$sb="11:00 AM";
$st=    date ( 'H:i:s', strtotime ($si) );
$en=date( 'H:i:s', strtotime ($sb ) );
$NoOfHours = $this->getTimesfromRange(date('H:i:s', strtotime($st)),date('H:i:s',strtotime($sb)));
print_r($NoOfHours);
```

function get time

```
public function getTimesfromRange($start, $end){
        $dates = array($start);
        while(end($dates) < $end){
            if(date('H:i:s', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 hour'))==$start){
              continue;
            }else{
              $dates[] = date('H:i:s', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 hour'));
            }
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

Question : how to not print first element in while loop, i tried use continue but not working.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919550/get-all-elements-in-array-besides-the-first-one-php

Comment: `continue` is correct. So if this is not working, it means your if statement is actually what's wrong

Comment: Make it a for loop instead and use if($i != 0){ }

Comment: @TomaszAdamczyk still trying some of these, my localhost seem slowly, **Andreas** thanks ill try

Comment: @Muklas I added an answer but I'm not sure it's correct. You have $end, not sure what that is for and how to get it in to the code. I made an answer to loop from 1-> end of array

Comment: @Andreas still stuck in localhost loading, something wrong with my xampp. ill try your code later, And mark as the accepted answer who answered first and correctly. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're getting the correct dates in your array but you want to print everything except element 0.

Personally I would simply copy it and remove element 0.

```
$NoOfHours = $this->getTimesfromRange(date('H:i:s', strtotime($st)),date('H:i:s',strtotime($sb)));
$printable = $NoOfHours;
unset($printable[0]);
var_dump($printable);
```

Answer (score 2):

The array_shift() function removes the first element from an array, and returns the value of the removed element. You can change your function as below to work. You can find more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shift.asp)

```
public function getTimesfromRange($start, $end){
    $dates = array($start);        
    while(end($dates) < $end){
        $dates[] = date('H:i:s', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 hour'));
    }
    array_shift($dates);
    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: sorry! my mistake to return the result of array_shift. `array_shift()` remove the first element from an array, and return the value of the removed element. So we should apply `array_shift()` on the array and then need to return the array itself. Updated the code. You can evaluate the same [here](https://eval.in/815150)

Comment: i was suppose too, i think return array_shift and return dates are same, nice solution thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change this code `$dates = array($start);` to `$dates = [];` which will not store the $start to your array. And you have to modify your function like this, **[Live demo](https://eval.in/814894)**.

```
 function getTimesfromRange($start, $end){
        $dates = [];
        while(end($dates) < $end){
              $date = end($dates) != FALSE ? end($dates) : $start;
              $dates[] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($date.' +1 hour'));
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

You also can remove the first element from the result array, with

`array_shift($result);` or `unset($result[0]);` or `array_slice($result, 1);`. These are not recormended.

Comment: $dates = [] just print one result.,  unset is working now

Comment: Change `$dates = array($start);` to `$dates = [];` should worked with your function. This modification only scape the first element in the array.

Comment: not working @Kris Roofe,  `$dates = [];` only print single array, unset is working fine, but mkaatman is first time answer. thanks Kris

Comment: @Muklas, I've make a test here. There are some code with your funciton need to be modified, check it here.https://eval.in/814894. I think not save the first element will be better than to remove the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's the first value that you don't want to display regardless of the time you could use a counter `$i;`

```
public function getTimesfromRange($start, $end){
        $dates = array($start);
        $i = 0;
        while(end($dates) < $end){
            if($i != 0){
              $dates[] = date('H:i:s', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 hour'));
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't `continue;` expendable as in not needed? If I is zero it will go in {}. And if that says continue or is empty makes no difference? Or am I wrong?

Comment: absolutely correct continue is redundant - it could be rewritten better actually - thar we go

Comment: by logic it seem working, when i try it  first element still printed

Comment: The issue must definitely be the expression in your if statement. To find out why on the first iteration instead of trying to skip it, var_dump both of the values in the if statement and work from there

Answer (score 1):

For loop to exclude [0]

```
public function getTimesfromRange($start, $end){
        $dates = array($start);
        For($i=0; $i<count($dates)); $i++){
           If($i != 0){
              $dates[] = date('H:i:s', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 hour'));
            }
        }
        return $dates;
    }
```

Comment: okeArray ( [0] => 06:00:00 ) .. your code only print first element.. thanks Andreas for answer